# Javascript function formatting

Tags: javascript

I'm concerned my if condition is not correctly formatted.
Does this look right to you?

```
function validateCoupon( form ){

if (form.textCoupon.value.length ){

    if (form.textCoupon.value.toLowerCase() == "Item01") {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Coupon', 'Activated', 'Item01']);
    }

    if (form.textCoupon.value.toLowerCase() == "Item02") {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Coupon', 'Activated', 'Item02']);
    }

$.get( "/include/checkCoupon.php", { coupon: form.textCoupon.value }, validateShipping );
}
     else {
    form.textCoupon.style.border = '';
    validateShipping( "yes" );
     }
return false; 
}
```

Comment: Your toLowerCase == 'Item01' check will never pass because Item01 isn't lower case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this were my code, this would be how I wrote it:

```
var validateCoupon = function (form) {
    var textCoupon = form.textCoupon,
        value = textCoupon.value,
        track = function (value) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Coupon', 'Activated', value]);
        };

    if (value.length) {
        if (value === 'Item01' || value === 'Item02') {
            track(value);
        }

        $.get('/include/checkCoupon.php', { coupon: value }, validateShipping);
    } else {
        textCoupon.style.border = '';
        validateShipping('yes');
    }

    return false;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Eli, this definitely works perfectly! No more if issues too =)

Answer (score 1):

Well, something appears to be a redundancy: `form.textCoupon.value` could be **Item01** or **Item02**. If it's one it couldn't be the other, so I'd suggest you a **switch** statement.

Another problem is if you call `.toLowerCase()` this never will return **Item01** but **item01**, and string equality is case-sensitive. Either call this function to both parts of condition or just don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting of the source code is irrelevant to the JavaScript runtime. It's just a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid tabs in indentation: they are not rendered identically on all platforms.

Comment: Ah, I see. And what about IDE way of indent code? Does Visual Studio, Eclipse and so allow such way of indentation?

Comment: Exactly: both Visual Studio and Eclipse can be configured to insert spaces instead of tabs.